# Wordpress custom posts and custom taxonomy logics

Tags: wordpress

I'm confused about the proper way of structuring the content. For example there's a fashion blog. There's a parent category "fashion news" with children categories: "news" and "collections". I'd like to create a database of models, brands and photographers. For each model (brand / photographer) there shall be an individual page like site.com/models/lara-stone. This page includes basic description, photo gallery (this should be implemented just as a post in WP) as well as special fields like "weight" and "height" for models (custom post?) and below all this there shall be all posts under category "fashion news" / "collections" related to the model (brand / photographer). On the main category page "fashion" I would like to have lists of brands / models / photographers. When creating a new blog post, the author should be able to choose the right model / brand / photographer. How do I structure all this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

ever heard of paragraphs.. on topic:
Make a custom posttypes of content that has it's own fields/properties.

Like models you will have to add [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) for height and weight.
For properties that might have multiple values consider tags/categories like
a model works both for brand X and Y

Then on the category page of brand you can get all models.

I hope this helps you on your way.
**Tip get a big paper/whiteboard and draw all relations/structure how you would like to have it regardless of restrictions a system gives you.**